# Provider-hosted app installs, throws file exists error

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SP2013 Provider-hosted app with DevExpress controls that was working fine until just recently. I am getting the following error when I try to F5 DEBUG:

> "Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The
>   file exists."

The app actually installs and executes but the debugger detaches very quickly plus it is prompting with the nagging aforementioned message. There are no AppUninstall / AppInstall / AppUpgraded events being handled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you; the error was because Visual Studio was not running as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have a break point somewhere that can be hit.
2. Do a Clean and Build, then run as debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was deploying to a remote dev server and the "run as administrator" option did not fix this error. What worked for me was logging on to the server and removing the app via the following powershell commands.

```
$instances = Get-SPAppInstance -Web <URL>
$instance = $instances | where {$_.Title -eq '<app_title>'}
Uninstall-SPAppInstance -Identity $instance
```

(Powershell commands taken from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161233.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

It appeared that Visual Studio was not successfully removing the app before re-deploying it. Once the app was removed using the above technique and I can now deploy from Visual Studio again.